# How to stop a scroll animation from rapidly triggering based on window position

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx, react-bootstrap

In react.js and react-bootstrap, I have a navbar that becomes smaller in height once the user starts scrolling down:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';
import './Navbar.css';

const Navbar = () => {
  const [navbar, setNavbar] = useState(false);

  const changeBackground = () => {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= 110) {
      setNavbar(true);
    } else {
      setNavbar(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', changeBackground);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', changeBackground);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <Navbar
      className={navbar ? 'shadow navSmall' : ''}
      bg={navbar ? 'light-subtle' : 'white'}
      variant="light"
      sticky="top"
      expand="lg"
    >
      ...
    </Navbar>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Once the user scrolls 110px the navSmall class is applied which changes the components height via a transition animation. This works fine, except that if the scroll position is set to exactly 110px, the animation starts rapidly spazzing out, switching between the navSmall and default styling. How do I fix this behaviour?

Comment: well, you are going to get your`changeBackground` called dozens of times because you add a listener every time it renders and you never remove it.

Comment: Yeah I see, what would be the better approach to apply the animation on scroll?

Comment: The usual way to attach event listeners in React is within a `useEffect` hook (with a non-null dependency argument), which allows React to manage the lifespan of your listener for you.

Comment: For your core issue, I would recommend setting some breakpoints and looking at the different scroll/offset values while it is "spazzing out", but the eventual realization should be that the size of your navbar should not change the scroll height of your page, or this fringe behavior is going to happen.  Probably `position: fixed`, `position: sticky`, or `position: absolute` will be what you end up wanting to look at.

Comment: yeah, the problem will be that adding the navbar will change the scroll offset, which then causes it to be removed, which causes it to be added, and so on...

Comment: i mean...I think just removing your ELSE case in `changeBackground` would help a lot. Once they scroll down, start the animation, and then just leave it. You don't need to hide it if they scroll back up

Comment: @GarrGodfrey For some context, I am trying to replicate this navbar behavior: https://csec.club/

Comment: @Jake I've updated my code to use useEffect - is that what you meant? However, the issue still presists

Comment: also "position:sticky" is automatically applied through the react-bootstrap "sticky=top" prop in the navbar component I believe.

Comment: something about the style changes is changing the size of the page or window. Often, it can be changing the width, causing a horizontal scroll bar to appear, which changes the height of the window.